# Suppose I declare an int but don't initialize it; what value is it? Can someone clear this up for me?

Tags: c++

Can someone help me get a better understanding of creating variables in `C++`? I'll state my understanding and then you can correct me.

---

```
int x;
```

Not sure what that does besides declare that `x` is an integer on the stack.

---

```
int x = 5;
```

Creates a new variable `x` on the stack and sets it equal to `5`. So empty space was found the stack and then used to house that variable.

```
int* px = new int;
```

Creates an anonymous variable on the heap. `px` is the memory address of the variable. Its value is `0` because, well, the bits are all off at that memory address.

```
int* px = new int;
*px = 5;
```

Same thing as before, except that the value of the integer at memory address `px` is set to 5. (Does this happen in 1 step???? Or does the program create an integer with value 0 on the heap and **then** set it to 5?

I know that everything I wrote above probably sounds naive, but I really am trying to understand this stuff.

Comment: Bung on all the compiler warnings. Initialise all variables. Of course the compiler will just initialise it to 5 and not bother with initialise it to zero first.

Comment: You say "Of course" like I should know this, but I'm new to programming and don't understand compilers as well as you guys do. I was hoping to learn from this thread.

Comment: How do you know that all bits are off at the address from `new`?

Comment: @user3537336 - I am sorry if it came over that way. The compiler is lazy and therefore will just bung in a 5 instead of zero.

Comment: Whether `int x;` creates a variable on the stack or in the data area of the executable depends on where it is (inside a function or not). Outside any function it is global and thus part of the executable, in a sense.

Comment: " the bits are all off at that memory address." is generally not the case. C (and by succession, and for the same reasons, C++) do NOT initialize memory before it is used. The reason surely is efficiency. If the user needs it initialized, s/he must do so explicitly. That also explains why globals and statics are initialized: It comes with no runtime cost attached.

Comment: Peter: Your last comment about statics and globals is not quite true. Zeroing (or default constructing) globals does cost something at (the start of) runtime, but we hope that this cost is negligible compared with what the program spends most of its time doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have answered this question from the point of view of how the C++ standard works. My only additional comment there would be with global or static variables. So if you have

```
int bar ()
{
    static int x;
    return x;
}
```

then `x` doesn't live on the stack. It will be initialised to zero at the "start of time" (this is done in a function called `crt0`, at least with GCC: look up "BSS" segments for more information) and `bar` will return zero.

I'd massively recommend looking at the assembled code to see how a compiler actually treats what you write. For example, consider this tiny snippet:

```
int foo (int a)
{
    int x, y;

    x = 3;
    y = a;

    return x + y;
}
```

I made sure to use the values of x and y (by returning their sum) to ensure the compiler didn't just elide them completely. If you stick that code in a file called `tmp.cc` and then compile it with

```
$ g++ -O2 -c -o tmp.o tmp.cc
```

then ask for the disassembled code with objdump, you get:

```
$ objdump -d tmp.o 

tmp.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_Z3fooi>:
   0:   8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
   4:   83 c0 03                add    $0x3,%eax
   7:   c3                      ret
```

Whoah! What happened to x and y? Well, the point is that the C and C++ standards merely require the compiler to generate code that has the same behaviour as what your program asks for. In fact, this program loads 32 bits from the stack (this is the contents of `a`, a fact dictated by the ABI on my particular platform) and sticks it in the `eax` register. Then it adds three and returns. Another important fact about the ABI on my laptop (and probably yours too) is that the return value of a function sits in `eax`. Notice, the function didn't allocate any memory on the stack at all!

In fact, I also put `bar` (from above) in my tmp.cc. Here's the resulting code:

```
00000010 <_Z3barv>:
  10:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  12:   c3                      ret
```

"Huh, what happened to `x`?", I hear you say :-) Well, the compiler spotted that nothing in the code required `x` to actually exist, and it always had the value zero. So the function basically got transformed into

```
int bar ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Magic!

Answer (score 2):

When a new variable is created, it does not have a value. It can be anything, pretty much depending on what was in that piece of stack or heap before. `int x;` will give you a warning if you try to use the value without setting it to something first. E.g. `int y = x;` will cause a warning unless you give `x` an explicit value first.

Creating an `int` on the heap works pretty much the same way: `int *p = new int;` calls the default constructor, which does nothing, leaving the value of `*p` up to chance until you set it to something explicit. If you want to make sure your heap value is initialized, use `int *p = new int(5);` to tell the constructor what value to copy into the memory it allocates.

Unless you initialize an `int` variable to zero explicitly, it is pretty much never initialized for you unless it is a global, namespace, or class static.

Comment: I don't understand how something can be "not initialized". Does it not correspond to a physical location in memory? Does not everything in memory have a value? For instance, if you declared a short int without initializing it, that short int still corresponds to some pattern of 8 bits in memory. Right?

Comment: @user3537336, right, there is ***SOMETHING*** there but it is essentially junk data that is useless and thus considered not initialized(aka, given a known value).

Comment: How exactly does "junk data" accumulate? I thought that as soon as data was no longer needed, it was cleared from memory.

Comment: "Unless you initialize an int variable to zero explicitly, it is pretty much never initialized for you.": Not true for globals, namespace, class static variables (and I believe also for function statics). Those are all default initialized, which is 0 for numeric types.

Comment: @user3537336 All "cleared from memory" means is that that part of memory is available to be written to again. Example: when you "delete" a file on a computer, it does not "go away", that part of memory stays and is "flagged" to be available for writing. Unless, you SPECIFICALLY overwrite that section of data right away after it is made available.

Comment: @bwtrent Thanks for that post. I thought that deleting memory on a computer literally reset the bits to zero!

Answer (score 0):

In `VS2010` specifically(other compilers may treat it differently), an `int` is not given a default value of `0`. You can see this by trying to print out a non-initialized `int`. It does allocate memory with a size of `int` but it is not initialized(just junk).

In both of your cases, the memory is allocated FIRST, and then the value is set. If a value is not set, you have a non-initialized part of memory that will have "junk data" inside of it and you will get a compiler warning and possibly an error when running it.

Yes, it has an address in memory but there is no valid(known) data inside of it unless you specifically set it. It vary well could be ***anything*** that the compiler recognizes as available memory to be overwritten. Since it is unknown and not reliable, it is considered junk and useless and why compilers warn you about it.

Compilers WILL set `static int` and global `int` to `0`.

EDIT: Due to Peter Schneider's comment.